# Scalameta's Semantic API

Tags: scala, scalameta, scalafix, semanticdb

In [Scalameta's tutorial](http://scalameta.org/tutorial/#SemanticAPI), it notes that the Semantic API can be used for name resolution (`println` => `_root_.scala.Predef.println`).  The FAQ "How do I use the Semantic API?" links to [scalafix](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/#scalacenter/scalafix.g8), but I was unable to find a tutorial or concrete examples.  So I'm still unclear.  Can someone point me to some specific examples or a tutorial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received the following answer from Ólafur Páll Geirsson on [gitter](https://gitter.im/scalameta/scalameta):

> you can try InteractiveSemanticdb
>   https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/master/scalameta/interactive/src/main/scala/scala/meta/interactive/InteractiveSemanticdb.scala
>
> it's part of the interactive module

With it I was able to answer all my questions.